# Enterprise Keywords and keywords in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, enterprise-keywords

what is enterprise keywords  in sharepoint 2013 and how it is useful for improve search results?
How to create keywords?

Comment: Did you try to google before asking? See ex. this for a dense explanation: http://www.siolon.com/blog/demystifying-the-enterprise-keywords-column/

Comment: Are these keywords only for documents or other libraries? Not pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Enterprise Keywords is a default column that is turned on out of the box in SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013.
>
> Enterprise Keywords is a managed metadata column that may be  populated with three things:
>
> 1. Any terms from the SharePoint Term Store. This includes any terms from any taxonomy/term set as well as any “Managed Keywords”.
> 2. If a document is checked into SharePoint that already has tags associated with it, then those tags will be added to the Enterprise Keywords field automatically at time of check in.  Most documents added to SharePoint won't have this metadata (because most people don't take the time to add keyword metadata to documents), but some will.   These keywords will then show up in the term store under “Managed Keywords”
> 3. If the term store administrator has made the “Managed Keywords” term set an open term set, then users can enter any keyword they wish into the Enterprise Keywords column.  Management of these user-generated tags should be part of your SharePoint governance process

Source: [How is the Enterprise Keywords column used in SharePoint?](http://blog.wandinc.com/2013/05/how-is-enterprise-keywords-column-used.html)

To add Enterprise Keyword check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-list-or-library-314ce556-e4bf-4ef7-9939-6a1bedfc434a?CorrelationId=1c193cf7-d3c9-46cf-a32c-9179c7a59088&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102832526)

Comment: When copy pasting large paragraphs like this, make sure to make that very clear, with a visible reference to the source